# When selecting a byobu session to resume it just creates a new one instead, how can I fix this?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, putty, byobu, tmux

Basically when I connect to the server using ssh I get the list of all sessions as I've used `byobu-enable` but it doesn't seem to be working properly. It is running with tmux as back-end. The server is running Ubuntu 18.04 and if it matters, the fish shell. I currently use the Putty fork Kitty to connect to it as it fixes an arrow key issue in Putty.

**The issue:**

I have connected using two ssh sessions at the same time and renamed their byobu sessions to "ASession" and "AnotherSession". I then disconnect both ssh sessions and reconnect in a new Putty instance and get presented with this message:

[I choose session 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcvVb.png)

It seems correct so far but when I have selected one of them it instead creates a new session with the same name but with random numbers as a suffix:

[I run `byobu ls` for this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcx4k.png)

I would expect it to not create this new session, at least as long as no one else is attached to the existing session. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me why it would create a new one every time I connect when I specifically tell it not to.

Have I just misconfigured it or is there some kind of bug here?